# Builing a fence on the property, concerns about flooding or more on the property

Tags: fence

I'm renting a house. The landlord says she's having a fence put up around the house. Neighbor behind me says if she puts up a fence then when it floods water will stay in the fenced in area and just flood worse and might come inside. Is this true or is the neighbor just saying this because he does not want her to put up a fence?

How to build a fence that will not create flood stagnant water.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Fences come in all sorts of varieties. Some will do a reasonable job of holding back water, others (I'm looking at you chain link) not so much. The fence type will determine _some_ of the issue. More important are the type of soil and the general direction of the slope of the land. If your property is already in a low-lying area, the fence _could_ increase the risk of flooding. If you're at the top of a hill, it probably wouldn't matter at all. Please [edit] some of these details into your question.

Comment: Additionally, if the neighbor doesn't want a fence up, he needs to take it up with the town zoning/planning/building commission quite soon. If the fence needs a permit to go up, the neighbors will get a chance to have their opinion heard. Trying to scare you with threats of flooding won't make any difference to the permitting office.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour]. We're not a discussion forum., and questions are expected to have enough detail that we can provide answers. Also, we have no idea what your neighbor thinks. That's not our business, and such questions are off topic here.

Comment: why do you care what the neighbor thinks?

Answer (score 2):

A fence with openings won't create a flooding problem.  The opening could be at the bottom between the fence and ground or between fence slats (or chain link/chicken wire/barbed wire).

A solid fence that goes all the way to ground level will act like a wall and might create a flooding problem.